# How to set default value for table column in nhibernate 3.2 using Mapping By Code?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I was using Fluent NHibernate as mapping mechanism for my NHibernate projects. But when it came to NHibernate 3.2, I realized that it has mapping by code built in, and no Fluent Nhibernate releases will be published for NHibernate 3.2.

I encountered a question when I want to set a default value for a entity property, I didn't find the API to do that. Can anybody give some advice?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't used mapping by code yet, but the `NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Impl.ColumnMapper` class has a method `Default(object defaultValue)`. [This issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2815) in NHibernate's JIRA, apart from pointing out a caveat, shows how to use it:

```
mapper.Class<MyDomainObject>(map => map.Property
    (s => s.TermService, 
        pm => pm.Column(cm => cm.Default("'my default value'"))));
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 5):

I found this code. May help u.

```
        Property(x => x.Property, m =>
        {
            m.Column("columnName");
            // or
            m.Column(c =>
            {
                c.Name("columnName");
                c.Default("defaultValue");
                c.SqlType("varchar(max)");
                c.Length(SqlClientDriver.MaxSizeForLengthLimitedString + 1);
                c.NotNullable(true);
                c.Check("len(columnName) > 1");
                c.Precision(2);
                c.Scale(2);
                c.Index("column_idx");
                c.Unique(true);
                c.UniqueKey("column_uniq");
            });
            m.Type<string>(); // or IUserType
            m.Update(true);
            m.Insert(true);
            m.Formula("arbitrary SQL expression");
            m.Access(Accessor.Field); // or Accessor.Property or Accessor.NoSetter
            // or
            m.Access(typeof(CustomAccessor));
            m.OptimisticLock(false);
            m.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Insert); // or PropertyGeneration.Always or PropertyGeneration.Never
            m.Lazy(true);
        });
```

Comment: In the future, it is very helpful if you can explain exactly how the code you provide works - the more details, the better!

Comment: I recognize this code, it's from someone else's blog. http://notherdev.blogspot.ca/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html

Answer (score 1):

When using a DataBase first, setting the default value in the mapping doesn´t work.
You have to tell the nhibernate to work with the DataBase Default value.
To do that, first you set the default value for the column in your Database.

After that, you tell the nhibernate mapping to ignore the column at insert by doing this:

```
Property(x => x.PropertyName, map =>
        {   map.Insert(false);
            map.Column("FL_COLUMN");                
            map.NotNullable(true);
        });
```